# Express handler called again without client request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

In the code below, the client `POST`s some data to `/somewhere` and then the route handler callback is executed.

Inside the callback I'm waiting for a `Promise` to resolve before I send some result back to the client.

The Promise will take quite some time to resolve. This is expected.

I don't know how long it will take because at around 2-3 minutes into the Promise execution the `app.post('/somewhere')` handler is called again, even though the client makes no such request (checked). There is no activity on the client during all this time, no page refresh, redirect..nothing.

Also, no errors are thrown from `forSomethingReallySlow()` as nothing relevant is logged on the Node console. And I have extensive logs from within `forSomethingReallySlow()` where everything is working fine until the handler is called again and `forSomethingReallySlow()` restarts.

```
app.use(cors({
   origin: '*',
   credentials: true,
   optionSuccessStatus: 200
}))

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET')
  next()
})

app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}))
app.use(session({
  secret: 'googoogaga',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID      : FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret  : FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL   : "http://localhost:4200/facebook/callback",
  profileFields : ['id']
}, async(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
  let facebookId = profile.id
  let userInDb =  await DB.getUser()
  if (userInDb && userInDb.facebookId === facebookId) {
    await DB.updateUser({ accessToken })
    done(null, userInDb)
  } else {
    let newUser = await DB.updateUser({ facebookId, accessToken })
    done(null, newUser)
  }
}))

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user)
})

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user)
})


app.post('/somewhere', ensureLoggedIn('/auth/facebook'), jsonParser, async function(req, res){

  console.log('new POST request at: ', new Date())

  let result = await forSomethingReallySlow(req.body)

  res.status(200).send({ result })

})
```

Is there some internal Express feature that re-calls a handler if it takes too long to respond?
And can I disable it ?
Or is there something else wrong ? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooooo 2 minutes sounds awfully close to the default timeout setting on express which is 120 seconds! Can you try this res.connection.setTimeout(0); right when the function starts?

Comment: https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login#ensure-authentication

Comment: [It's a function call--that returns a function.](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-ensure-login/blob/master/lib/ensureLoggedIn.js) Function generators are used fairly often in the ecosystem; it can look "off", but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: Fair, I was not aware of how passport.js worked! Besides that, though-- are you calling from the browser or from Postman? I've had instances where the browser tries to submit another request on its own. Specially Safari

Comment: ok so they have a weird setup, thanks for the FYI! :)

Comment: From the browser (Chrome), on localhost.

Comment: And the network tab does not contain 2 requests? You can always console.log the headers to see what's in them too! Like where this came from and what not!

Comment: I'm logging the fetch request on the browser console and it's only executing once. There's no second request going out logged on the Network panel either. There is only still the first one, still marked as pending.

Comment: When you put a `console.log("/somewhere evoked")` right before `let result = await forSomethingReallySlow(req.body)` do you see the log twice?

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing that, actually logging the Date as well. The handler is called again right after 2 minutes.

Comment: Oooooo 2 minutes sounds awfully close to the default timeout setting on express which is 120 seconds! can you try this `res.connection.setTimeout(0);` right when the function starts?

Comment: Yes, that was it! :) You can update your answer, thanks!